# How can I root my HTC One for T-Mobile using ADB?

Tags: rooting, adb, fastboot, htc, htc-one

I want to use ADB. FastBoot isn't working on my OS X machine.

```
 ./fastboot devices
```

lists nothing.

```
 ./adb devices
```

shows my device

I downloaded SuperSu from the Google Play store but it says it I had to manually root my phone if I am running 4.3 (which I am).

Can anyone please tell me how to use ADB to root my device? ISIS Mobile Wallet app thinks my phone is rooted.

Comment: Try running fastboot as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a website called [HTCOneRoot.com](http://www.htconeroot.com) I guess you can find instructions there (videos at the right side, scroll down)